# Owl Carousel fade effect not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I'm trying to apply the fade effect on a Owl Carousel but it does not seem to work.

As you can see in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/lav911/fHa6J/ , I'm loading the `transitions.css` file mentioned in their [docs](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/transitions.html).

Am I missing something? Why does it slide instead of fading ? Also, notice the fade does not work even on their site.

**Later edit:** It seems to fade on Google Chrome 35 and Firefox, but on Google Chrome 36 it will slide. Strange.

Comment: in this URL here , http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/transitions.html Where is fade effect? i cant see

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird yes, that's what I mention in my post as well. See the later edit.

Comment: Can u give link to Proper code of Own caraosel where I can see fade effect?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was reported apparently on the plugin's github repo - https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel/issues/346

Simply using this [version of the plugin](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iamphill/OwlCarousel/a2bcc904908ae1417d01a85bf024c7c88c2f95ee/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js) (pull-request) fixed it.

Comment: ... fixes Chrome, yes, but breaks Internet Explorer (at least 11, that's all I can test)

Comment: not recommended. this breaks on IE9. and later. tested on BrowserStack. don't use this pull-request fix.

Comment: new: now you can use version 2.4 http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/index.html with animate.css to make slider transitions.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that owl plugin includes IE10 and 11 among the browsers that don't support CSS transform. So you can use owl carousel in combination with Modernizr and replace the "support3d" variable:

```
support3d = (asSupport !== null && asSupport.length === 1);
```

with

```
support3d = (Modernizr.csstransforms3d);
```

that seems to solve it! :)

Comment: This worked brilliantly. No idea what it does, but it fixes the issue in Chrome!

Comment: It uses [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to check if the current browser support CSS Transforms, also you should check for `Modernizr.csstransitions`

Answer (score 5):

Since chrome now both supports -webkit-transform and the transform property, the owl code fails, since its 3dsupport detection is only returning true if the returned array (of transform styles) is equal to 1, simply change this line:

```
support3d = (asSupport !== null && asSupport.length === 1);
```

To this line:

```
support3d = (asSupport !== null && asSupport.length > 0);
```

And it should work ;)

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
support3d = (asSupport !== null && asSupport.length == 1);
```

to

```
support3d = (asSupport !== null && asSupport.length >= 1);
```

https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel/issues/515

Answer (score 1):

From update 1.3.2 all transitions styles are moved out from main owl.carousel.css file to owl.transitions.css

Link owl.transitions.css in your head or import it in your css.